# Find Closest Vector from a List of Vectors | Python

Tags: python, vector, distance

If you are given say a list of 10 vectors, called A that represent different groups. Then you have a time series of vectors v1,v2,...,vn, each being a vector as well. I was wondering if there was a way to find the "closest" vector in A for each v1,v2,...,vn if you define some distance metric?

Is there a quick way to do this besides for looping through and just comparing all entries?

Edit: No I am not asking how to do k-means or something like that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I classify data with the nearest-neighbor algorithm using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326958/how-can-i-classify-data-with-the-nearest-neighbor-algorithm-using-python)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the [spatial KDtree in scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html). It uses a fast tree algorithm to identify close by points for vectors of arbitrary dimension.

*Edit*: sorry, if you are looking for [arbitrary distance metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/704234/577108), a Tree like structure might still be an option.

Here is an example:

```
>>> from scipy import spatial
>>> A = [[0,1,2,3,4], [4,3,2,1,0], [2,5,3,7,1], [1,0,1,0,1]]
>>> tree = spatial.KDTree(A)
```

This sets up the KDTree with all the points in A, allowing you to perform fast spatial searches within it.
Such a query takes a vector and returns the closest neighbor in A for it:

```
>>> tree.query([0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5])
(1.1180339887498949, 3)
```

The first return value is the distance of the closest neighbor and the second its position in A, such that you can obtain it for example like this:

```
>>> A[ tree.query([0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5])[1] ]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Hmm I see. So I should feed in my matrix A that has the "10 different vectors (groups)" to the KDTree. Then do I just simply loop through my entire series of interest and do tree.query(data[i])? I tried that and the output isn't very intuitive and the documentation for this method was very lacking...

Comment: Yes, though you could hand it all points at once as well. Per default query returns the closest vector in A to the given one. And it returns the distance to that vector and the position of the closest vector in A.

Comment: @haraldkl If you had two nested lists, rather than a single value and a nested list, what would be an efficient way of doing this over all values and storing the result?

Comment: Can I visualize the built KD-Tree ?

Answer (score 1):

If you define a metric, you can use it in the [min](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) function:

```
closest = min(A, key=distance)
```

Comment: very clean, but sounds like OP is asking for a fast way of finding the closest vector within A to *each* vector in A though

Answer (score 1):

So some sample code is:

```
# build a KD-tree to compare to some array of vectors 'centall'
tree = scipy.spatial.KDTree(centall) 
print 'shape of tree is ', tree.data.shape

# loop through different regions and identify any clusters that belong to a different region
[d1, i1] = tree.query(group1)
[d2, i2] = tree.query(group2)
```

This returns variables d and i. 
d stores the closest distance
i returns the index at which this happens

Hope this helps.